# Measuring electron position in covalent bond

Tags: quantum-mechanics

As covalent bond of a molecule is created by the molecular orbital wavefunction of valence electrons, if we measured position of a single electron with sufficient precision, could we collapse the wavefunction, thus breaking the bond?

Comment: Well, the wave function is the position of the electron...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever is the level of descritpion of the electronic state,  by electronic wavefunction of a molecule one means the lowest eigentsate of the electronic hamiltonian.

As a consequence of measurement of position, the electronic wavefunction, after the measurement, cannot remain an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian. The translation in physical terms of such general description of the measurement process implies that, as effect of the position measurement, the final energy of the system may be higher than the energy of the most energetic bound state and the bond can be destroyed. Which makes sense, if one thinks the most obvious way of measuring the  position of the electron:  scattering with high energy particles.